# Error InputMismach en el ultimo item de un ciclo que lee un TXT a traves de Scanner

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2, scanner, java-util-scanner

```
//METODO 2 -- CARGAR CONTENIDO EN EL VECTOR Y MATRIZ

public static void cargarValores(String nombreArchivo, String[] nombres, int[][] valores) throws IOException{
    Scanner archivo = new Scanner(new File(nombreArchivo));
    int fila, col;
    archivo.useDelimiter(",");
    for (fila = 0; fila < valores.length; fila++) {
        nombres[fila] = archivo.next();
        for (col = 0; col < valores[0].length; col++) {           
            valores[fila][col] = archivo.nextInt();
        }
    }
    archivo.close();
}


//.cargarValores ``ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO DE TEXT:

//1 NOMBRE, 10 VALORES INT

Barcelona,30,12,27,16,3,10,26,29,19,13
Ciudad Bolivar,9,12,7,31,14,16,9,13,10,30
Merida,35,26,20,12,2,25,34,13,28,18
Valencia,2,10,28,3,7,26,12,35,6,19
San Cristobal,28,7,23,16,1,18,22,32,4,26
Barinas,23,23,34,29,15,21,23,13,16,4
Caracas,2,12,18,18,27,12,14,26,18,4
Maracaibo,30,16,26,31,34,6,27,33,35,12
Los Teques,12,2,4,8,8,32,5,11,1,1
Puerto,35,26,11,32,21,22,25,26,10,21
```

Por que me lanza un error despues de leer el nombre de lugar y 9 numeros sin leer el 10mo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está pasando es que cuando llega al final (10mo numero) el scanner, como no ve una coma, coge también lo que va después.
Para arreglarlo basta con poner una coma después del último numero, así:

> Barcelona,30,12,27,16,3,10,26,29,19,13,
> Ciudad Bolivar,9,12,7,31,14,16,9,13,10,30,
> Merida,35,26,20,12,2,25,34,13,28,18,
> Valencia,2,10,28,3,7,26,12,35,6,19,
> San Cristobal,28,7,23,16,1,18,22,32,4,26,
> Barinas,23,23,34,29,15,21,23,13,16,4,
> Caracas,2,12,18,18,27,12,14,26,18,4,
> Maracaibo,30,16,26,31,34,6,27,33,35,12,
> Los Teques,12,2,4,8,8,32,5,11,1,1,
> Puerto,35,26,11,32,21,22,25,26,10,21